# Photoshop action and XML sidecar for showing dialogs only once?

Tags: xml, action, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I´m searching a possiblity to run a batch job inside of photoshop with actions. The actions have dialog boxes to adjust blur or something else.

Now I found this: [text](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/sample-script-to-save-preferences-to-xml/m-p/12187104)

Is it possible to save all settings while running an action for the first time and safe this next to the main psd file as a XML sidecar. So it would adjust all follow pictures with the preference. (like sidecar xml on lightroom). When I will run run the job again, it should load the sidecar. So it must check, if the sidecar is available. Or I can load this sidecar with a dialog and save this with a dialog prompt?

Because I will run this script first, than run several actions. One time with a "master action" starting the script and run actions, one time with image processor or other batch scripts (with actions load options) or with pixelsplaher smart replace script (here I´m able to import a jsx).

I´ve download the script on dropbox "XMLPrefs.jsx". This will only be a sample for scripting the variables from the sliders/text/checkbox you change inside the dialog. but how it will work with actions?

Another option would be fine to have is a script to temporary supress these dialog boxes in actions. I must do this manually next to the actions manager before running the action.

I will run actions in batch with an option to deactivate the dialog prompts temporary and save the preferences inside a sidecar xml for next running the action.